# Sum of json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have json type field, something like this

**data**

```
{"age": 44, "name": "Jun"}

{"age": 19, "name": "Pablo", "attempts": [11, 33, 20]}

{"age": 33, "name": "Maria", "attempts": [77, 10]}
```

Here some json data have "attempts" array, some not. When json have this array, I need get sum of array elements in different field, need result like

**data , sum_of_array**

```
{"age": 44, "name": "Jun"} , (nothing here)

{"age": 19, "name": "Pablo", "attempts": [11, 33, 20]} , 64

{"age": 33, "name": "Maria", "attempts": [77, 10]} , 87
```

Comment: What is your postgres version?

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.5.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT attempts.id,
       sum(vals.v::integer) sum_attempts
FROM attempts
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(val->'attempts') vals(v)
      ON TRUE
GROUP BY attempts.id;
```

Use `json_array_elements_text` if you are using `json` instead of `jsonb`.

Comment: This is a nasty trick. Is it documented that `->> 0` works on `jsonb` literals too?

Comment: Don't know, I guess it is an implementation artifact. But you can just as well write `vals.v::text::integer` instead.

Comment: yes, ofc (or the `jsonb_array_elements_text()` function). It's just surprised me.

Comment: Nice solution, but you have typo error,  just if OP uses json type, then shuold be `json_array_elements_text`

Comment: @pozs This is going off-topic, but if you look at `src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c` you'll find that a root scalar is stored in `jsonb` as an array with one element.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe wow, that's nice :D I guess it has something to do with the containment (`@>` and `<@`) semantics (there the literal values are replaceable with an array, holding that one literal; at least on the root level).

Comment: One question, how can I get another columns, when I try "SELECT tasks.data, sum(vals.v::integer) sum_attempts FROM tasks ..." shows error: "column "tasks.data" must appear in the GROUP BY"

Comment: Simple, do what the message says: For every expression you put into the `FROM` clause, add the same expression to the `GROUP BY` clause. In PostgreSQL you can also use the column number in the `GROUP BY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have unique `id` identity column in your table

```
SELECT your_table.*, tt.sum FROM your_table
LEFT JOIN (
    select id, SUM(arrvals) as sum FROM (
        select id, json_array_elements_text(CAST(your_json_column->>'attempts' AS json))::NUMERIC as arrvals  from your_table
    )t 
     group by id
) tt
ON your_table.id = tt.id
```

Comment: You could use `LATERAL` to simplify your JOIN (this will cause 2 table scans)